# Adding a button with a fixed position in the row

Tags: flutter

```
Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                OutlinedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.translate),
                  label: const Text("Button A"),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor), // I have getColor fuction
                    foregroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor2), // I have getColor2 fuction
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                  },
                  child: const Text("Button B"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Those are my code. I want to make Button A stay in the center. But when I add Button B, Button A go to the right. Does somebody know how to make Button A fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row() does a layout dynamically based on its children.
You could use Stack() which lets you control layout by wrapping each child in the children[] with either Align() or Positioned().
Positioned widget works similar to css position, where you need to define at least 2 of top, left, bottom, right.

```
Stack(
 Children: [
  Align(
   alignment: Alignment.Center,
   child: //Button A
  ),
  Align(
   alignment: Alignment.centerRight, //this might be a wrong value but it should have a right alignment prop
   child: //Button B
  ),
 ]
)
```

Comment: Can I make it non-overlapping?

Comment: Not with a Stack, since it is meant to Stack widgets on each other, you could control the width of the buttons but wrapping in a SizedBox widget.

Or just had this thought if you want to use a Row, you can have 3 widgets as children being a SizedBox, ButtonA, ButtonB, the sized box you would make the width so that the ButtonA would be where you want it